# Is my computer psu voltage normal?

Tags: power-supply

[image: Image Link]

As you can see：
 +3.3v minimum is only 0.24v，maximum can go up to 4.08v.
+5v maximum can go up to 6.12v.
+12v minimum is only 1.901v.
 Are these values normal?